# VueJS form with step="5" steps 1 the first time you step upwards or downwards

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Check this out:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: 100,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
  <input
    type="number"
    class="form-control"
    min="1"
    step="5"
    v-model.number="number"
  >
</div>
```

The first time you step, it steps by 1, and then after that it goes to 5.

Why is this? And how can you solve the issue? How do you get it to always step by 5?

Comment: it's very strange. I am sure about one thing. It is related to min :)

Comment: and has nothing to do with js or vue. It's pure html behavior  of `input` (check this out: https://jsbin.com/fazumigeye/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: With `min="1"` and `step="5"` the valid values are `1, 6, 11, 16, ..., 96, 101, 106, ...`

Comment: the doc (https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#number-state-typenumber) says somehting about (step mismatch: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#suffer-from-a-step-mismatch) maybe is related

Comment: @skirtle Are you sure those the only valid values? I thought that `step` just is about when the user presses the up arrow or the down arrow, how much it goes up or down. But that if the user wanted to, they could type in eg. 2.75 or whatever.

Comment: I guess that would depend on your definition of *valid* and what behaviour you expect for invalid values. From the perspective of pressing up and down they are the valid values. Beyond that it depends on the browser. In Firefox I see a red outline if I try to enter any other values. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally as @skirtle pointed out, since you have a `step`, the `min` value is very important for the input behavior... imagine otherwise you will not be able to step correctly.

As a workaround you can do something like this:

- remove min
- guard the min limit in js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    number: 100,
  },
  watch: {
    number: function(val) {
      if(val < 1) {
        this.number = 1;
      }
    }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ number }}</p>
  <input
    type="number"
    class="form-control"
    step="5"
    v-model.number="number"
  >
</div>
```